# getting error on running npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I used **npm install npm@latest -g**, to update the new version of npm.

but I am not able run npm. I don't know how to fix this. I have used some of the online guideline, but It didn't worked for me.

**getting error on npm**

```
.nvm/versions/node/v4.1.2/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:79
  let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})
  ^^^
SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) 
not yet supported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
    at startup (node.js:118:18)
    at node.js:952:3
```

Comment: what is the result of node -v?

Comment: I just manged to fix this. thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using nodeV4.1.2, it don't suppport it.
You can add `'use strict';` in line 1 or update node.